# Selecting Appropriate Forecast Performance Metrics for Long Forecast Periods and Limited Development Data

Tags: regression, forecasting

I have created a linear regression forecasting model that predicts out for eight data points with a dependent variable that is aggregated at the quarterly level. My development data sample was only 60 data points so obviously I'm concerned about over fitting. The main issue here is that I take the eight forecasted data points and aggregate them to get a final dollar amount like a total aggregated output to represent a two year forecast. Will typical metrics like MAPE and Forecast Bias assist me with monitoring performance of my model over time or is there a better metric I should consider?